# NASM Hello World on Linux: undefined reference to `main'

Tags: linux, nasm

I've been following [this tutorial](http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html) for an intro to assembly on Linux.

```
section .text
global _start ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:
        mov edx,len     ;message length
        mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
        mov ebx,1       ;file descriptior
        mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
        int 0x80        ;call kernel

        mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
        int 0x080       ;call kernel

section .data

msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa     ;the string
len equ $ - msg                 ;length of the string
```

I've then had problems compiling it. I've looked around and found (on SO) that I should compile it like this:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
gcc -o hello hello.o
```

But I keep getting this error from GCC:

```
hello.o: In function `_start':
hello.asm:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(NB: I'm running Debian Linux on a 64 bit Intel i7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add `-nostdlib` when linking your binary.

```
gcc -o hello hello.o -nostdlib
```

Comment: You would need `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -o hello hello.o -Wl,-melf_i386` otherwise the link will fail or produce a non-working executable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why would I want the linker to produce an `elf32-i386` executable from an `elf64-x86-64` object file ?

Answer (score 10):

If you are going to learn assembly, then you are much better served learning to use the assembler `nasm` and the linker `ld` without relying on `gcc`. There is nothing wrong with using `gcc`, but it masks part of the linking process that you need to understand going forward.

Learning assembly in the current environment (generally building on `x86_64` but using examples that are written in `x86 32-bit` assembler), you must learn to build for the proper target and the language (`syscall`) differences between the two. Your code example is `32-bit` assembler. As such your `nasm` compile string is incorrect:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm
```

The `-f elf64` attempts to compile a `64-bit` object file, but the instructions in your code are `32-bit` instructions. (It won't work)

Understanding and using `ld` provides a better understanding of the differences. Rather than using `gcc`, you can use `nasm` and `ld` to accomplish the same thing. For example (with slight modification to the code):

```
msg db 0xa, 'Hello, StackOverflow!', 0xa, 0xa     ;the string
```

You compile and build with:

```
nasm -f elf -o hello-stack_32.o hello-stack_32.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o hello-stack_32 hello-stack_32.o
```

**Note** the use of `-f elf` for `32-bit` code in the `nasm` call and the `-m elf_i386` linker option to create a compatible executable.

**output:**

```
Hello, StackOverflow!
```

If you are serious about learning assembler, there are a number of good references on the web. One of the best is [**The Art of Assembly**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html). (it is written primarily for `8086` and `x86`, but the foundation it provides is invaluable). In addition, looking at the executables you create in binary can be helpful. Take a look at [**Binary Vi (BVI)**](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/download.html). It is a good tool.

**bvi screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of BVI. What's the advantage of BVI over using VIM in hexeditor mode?

Comment: In binary files, there is no concept of a `newline`. `bvi` is tailored for this environment and provides `hex` & `ASCII` display side by side. Well worth the look. IIRC, it is a CMake build, so building from source is trivial.

Comment: What I mean is how is it different than doing `vim -b a.out` and then `:%!xxd`. This shows hex and ASCII side by side.

Comment: I tried `vim -b` and it was a mess. I've added a screenshot to my answer so you can compare.

Comment: You did `vim -b` and then `:%!xxd`?

Comment: Nope, just the first part `:)`, That's nice. Thanks for the follow up. I hadn't thought about processing the buffer through `xxd`. `bvi` provides the view natively.

Comment: Another useful hexdump is `objdump -s a.out`.