# Undefined reference to main in Assembly langage

Tags: assembly, nasm

Hi im trying to compile this code in order to display the max of 2 given values in assembly but apparently can't seem to make it.

The error is

```
/usr/bin/ld:
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:
   in function `_start': (.text+0x20):
   undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

And the code is

```
bits 64
global my_average
section .text

start:
 push rbp
 mov rbp, rsp

        xor rax, rax
        add rax, rdi
        add rbx, rsi
        cmp rax , rbx
        jge .end


.end:
 mov rax, rbx


mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

Comment: side note: `mov rax, rbx` will be always executed, probably it should be before `.end` label

Comment: Show us what commands are you using to compile your code. From the error it looks like youre using gcc which by default expects the main function to be present, but your question is tagged as nasm.

Comment: i am using  nasm -felf64 *.s && gcc *.o -o test && ./test 1 3

Comment: Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052397/5457426) should answer your question. Respond in the comments if it does.

Comment: Change `start` into `main` also obviously `global my_average` should be `global main`. PS: `rbx` is a callee saved register, better change to `rdx`. Also of course this won't take arguments as you expect and prints nothing. It's unclear what you are even adding, and `rbx` is uninitalized.

Answer (score 1):

At first i thought this was a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052123/nasm-hello-world-on-linux-undefined-reference-to-main) but the original question seems to be about 32-bits. While it is not relevant to the answer i think its worth to update the answer.

---

During linking with `ld` (which is usually called by `gcc` internally) the entry point into a binary is placed pointing to the `_start` symbol. This means that when the program is ran, it starts execution from this point. Despite that, the default starting point in a C program is usually a `main` function. This is due to the fact that C programs often link with various libraries. One of the better known ones is `libc`, but there is also [`libgcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html). Some of these libraries require some initialization to be performed when the program is started. This is often implemented by making `_start` call these initialization routines before calling `main`. The `_start` symbol used by `gcc` for that task is defined in `crt` (CRT stands for C RunTime). [Here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libgcc/config/i386/sol2-c1.S#L56/crt0.c#L196) is a link to `_start` in gcc source code, specifically the i386 version (64-bit version i could not find, but it is somewhere in there). Since the `_start` symbol is already defined, the programmer only has to define `main`.

Now you are not writing C, you are writing assembly. You most likely do not want any of the libraries you would normally want when writing C. You want `_start` to only call your program code, not initialize anything behind the scenes. But GCC does that by default, by passing options to the linker `ld`. You really have two solutions:

- Run GCC with `-nostdlib` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052168/5457426). This makes it so that GCC does not use default libraries, so no initialization is performed and CRT is not used. The link option is described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).
- Use `ld` directly, and learn in detail about the linking process as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052397/5457426). This is more difficult, but gives you better understanding of what you are actually doing. In my personal opinion, this fits assembly much better, unless only part of your code is in assembly and the rest is in C.

I personally recommend the second option for the sake of education and learning, but both should fix your problem.